# IdaPython Get Call Destination for Register Operand

Tags: ida, idapython

I'm trying to determine the destination address for call instructions. I can get this for calls that use an immediate but not for a call to an immediate-assigned register. How can I get the address of the function being called in a situation like this when Ida has inserted a pink comment with funcName?

```
mov eax, funcName
...
call eax ; funcName
```

Comment: How do you get the name where the call is immediate?

Comment: I get the address of the `extrn` line when the call is immediate by getting the instruction's `Operands[1].value`

Comment: Could you perhaps include a full example as part of your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA has a specific mechanism for storing and reading references (either code, data or both) to and from a specific instruction. That mechanism works whenever IDA successfully resolves a reference, which may not always be the case (think of `call eax` where `eax` is not easily resolved staticly). You should use that interface for all types of calls.

The function that best suits your use case is probably [`idautils.CodeRefsFrom`](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/python/idautils.py#L68) which accepts two parameters `ea` and `flow` and returns a generator for all code references from given `ea`. `flow` is a boolean used to control whether you wish the next instruction included.

There are a bunch of other related functions, such as `CodeRefsTo`, `DataRefsFrom`, `XrefsTo`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Either you use a debugger like OllyDbg and set a breakpoint at the location where the call is. Or you're looking at the previous code at the location where  `funcName` is written. If it is written dynamically, you go best with using a debugger.

Comment: Since Ida has already analyzed where the registers are set with immediate function addresses, is there a way to get the value without looking at the previous instructions or using a debugger?

Comment: How should this work? If the function address is loaded dynamically, for example with loading a library and then the address of an exported function via getProcAddress. IDA Pro can not predict where the function will be located. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have call instructions that call an address which Ida has labeled with the function name. The actual call address which I am trying to get just contains `extrn funcName`

Comment: Since IDA has that data available I believe OP just wanted to get it from IDA directly, without extracting the value from the register. The question was specifically for the `mov eax, <immediate> / call eax` couple lines.